# Execute Long Python Script From PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, phpmyadmin

I want to execute python script from PHP.
I use system("C:\python.exe. pythonfile.py ) in PHP to execute it, it executes fine but for only small scripts.
My python file takes around 5 minute to execute a code, but looks PHP only execute small scripts, can anyone help me, how to execute long python scripts from PHP & get return value from it.

Thanks

Comment: If your php script runs through a web server, than the problem you face is probably the timeout parameter of the web server or the php module of the web server. Find it and increase to an appropriate value.

Comment: I already increase by 20 minutes. set_time_limit(1200);

Comment: You can check max_execution_time as well.

Comment: If you provide more context, people may also help you finding a better approach for what you want to achieve. The requirement sounds like there's plenty of room for improvement (also in terms of security!)

Comment: Exactly I want to take input from PHP, pass it's input in Machine Learning Model in python & want to show its output back in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem. To escape from PHP timeout, I ran my script in background using PHP popen()/pclose(). It was something like that:

```
<?php 
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python pythonfile.py);
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
         pclose(popen("start /B " .$command, "r"));
    }else {
         exec($command2 . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
?>
```

Tip: if your Python script has some printouts like print(), you should comment all them due the internal buffer, to avoid unexpected closing.

More information about "START /B" inside popen() command, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start